# Get MySQL service/password/user from Helm dependency

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I would like to add https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/mysql as a dependency to my helm charts. So I added this to my Chart.yaml:

```
dependencies:
- name: mysql
  version: "6.14.9"
  repository: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
```

How can I now get the service name the password and the user as environment variables in my main chart deployments to connect to the mysql server? Somehow all the documentation of the chart only ever mentions directly installing it with helm. Is it not correct to use a dependency here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using a dependency you can override the values.yaml for mysql chart from the parent chart and then inject those values as an environment variable or a secret into your main container.

in values.yaml of parent chart

```
mysql:
 mysqlRootPassword: testing
 mysqlUser: user
 mysqlPassword: user
```

once you have these values you can use these values to create a secret and user volume mount or directly inject them as an environment variables.

For mysql server use the release name and chart name for most of the cases unless you are using a NameOverride or FullNameOverride

```
 env:
  - name: MYSQL_SERVER
    value: {{ .Release.Name }}-mysql
```

Comment: So is it not possible to get the name of the mysql secret/service in a way that allows others to overwrite the name? Eg using `{{ template "mysql.fullname" . }}`

Comment: You cannot use the child chart template in parent chart as the template will only be created when mysql chart is rendered and you might face an issue that the template is not defined..

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer here does not work.

For bitnami mysql 8.0.25, the correct syntax is:

```
mysql:
  auth:
    rootPassword: testing
    username: user
    password: user
```